# Trigger in a database that should change values in a table in a different database?

Tags: php, mysql

How to create a trigger that is activated by a change in a database which changes values in a table in a different database ?

One database contains the table which has the login information (usernames, passwords) . When a user logs in, values in a table in another database is to be updated.

How could this be achieved ?

**[edit]**

Sorry, yes, the two different databases are on the same database server.

**[Updated]**

I have `mainDB.users` table :

```
username | password | NumberLogins
---------|----------|--------------
         |          |
```

and a `otherDB.history` table :

```
username | points
---------|---------
         |
```

How do we increment the corresponding `points` after a user has logged in ?

```
USE `mainDB`;

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `updateUserInfo`;

DELIMITER ||

CREATE TRIGGER `updateUserInfo` 
    BEFORE UPDATE ON `users` 
    FOR EACH ROW

    BEGIN
        IF NEW.`NumberLogins`=5 THEN

            UPDATE `otherDB`.`history`
            SET `points` = `points` + 1,
            WHERE 
              `username`=NEW.`username`;

        END IF;

    END ||
```

I keep getting this error.

```
 #1442 - Can't update table 'history' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.
```

Comment: What kind of "other database"? Different server? Otherwise, just run the query and be informed that you can specify `database.tablename.columname` to access other tables and databases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume both DBs are on the same server.

```
USE name_of_db_trigger_to_be_in;
delimiter ||
create trigger.......

   UPDATE other_db.other_table
   SET other_guys = 'hohoho';


end||
```

Comment: Thanks. I seem to have another problem. I am to update the `other_db.other_table` with a value obtained from the `main_db.users` . I am stuck by the error -- `#1442 - Can't update table 'history' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.`

Comment: If the trigger is fired by an action performed on table A. The trigger CAN NOT touch table A with update/delete/insert. U need to modify the NEW.* OLD.* values. U will need to read more on SP/Triggers to see how it works